# Compare values in list of dicts in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comparison

I'm a newbie in Python. I have a list of members and a list of meetings (containing the member id):

```
memberList = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'Joe'},
{'id': '2', 'name': 'Jason'},
{'id': '3', 'name': 'Billy'}]

meetingList = [{'meetingId': '20', 'hostId' : '1'},
{'meetingId': '21', 'hostId' : '1'},
{'meetingId': '22', 'hostId' : '2'},
{'meetingId': '23', 'hostId' : '2'}]
```

Where the id of the member and the hostId of meeting is the same value.

Result: a list of member ids which has no meetings `['3']` or the list of dicts `[{'id': '3', 'name': 'Billy'}]`

What's the best and most readable way to do it?

Comment: Hi, is there a reason you are using a list of dict ? You could use a simpe dict with Ids as the key and name as value. It would be easier to handle and read in your case. Except if you have more "properties" for each member ? You could just use a dict like that:
memberDict = {1:'Joe', 2:'Jason', 3:'Billy'}. Same for the meetings;

Comment: I simplified the structure to make it more understandable, but the object is more complex with much more data :) and the meeting list is actually returned from API, I don't see the reason to do operations on it if I just need a simple values comparison. Meeting list is smt like:
{"uuid": "xx", "id": "yy", "host_id": "zz", "topic": "Topic", "type": "8", "start_time": "2020-12-01T08:15:00Z", "duration": "30", "timezone": "Europe/Berlin", "created_at": "2020-11-10T13:46:38Z", "join_url": "https://xxx"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of hosts and then use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out the members:

```
member_list = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'Joe'},
               {'id': '2', 'name': 'Jason'},
               {'id': '3', 'name': 'Billy'}]

meeting_list = [{'meetingId': '20', 'hostId': '1'},
                {'meetingId': '21', 'hostId': '1'},
                {'meetingId': '22', 'hostId': '2'},
                {'meetingId': '23', 'hostId': '2'}]

# create a set of hosts
hosts = set(meeting['hostId'] for meeting in meeting_list)  # or { meeting['hostId'] for meeting in meeting_list }

# filter out the members that are in hosts
res = [member['id'] for member in member_list if member['id'] not in hosts]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': '3', 'name': 'Billy'}]
```

For the *id* only output, do:

```
res = [member['id'] for member in member_list if member['id'] not in hosts]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['3']
```

Comment: did you put the underscores on purpose? is it more standard for dicts or for python in general?

Comment: @holly.woo Yes I did. For python in general

Answer (score 0):

I'd extract out the id's from both lists of dictionaries and compare them directly.

First I'm just rewriting your list variables to assign them with `=`.
Using `:` won't save the variable.

```
memberList = [{'id': '1', 'name': 'Joe'},
              {'id': '2', 'name': 'Jason'},
              {'id': '3', 'name': 'Billy'}]

meetingList = [{'meetingId': '20', 'hostId' : '1'},
               {'meetingId': '21', 'hostId' : '1'},
               {'meetingId': '22', 'hostId' : '2'},
               {'meetingId': '23', 'hostId' : '2'}]
```

Then use list comprehension to extract out the id's from each list of dicts.

```
member_id_list = [i["id"] for i in memberList]
meeting_hostid_list = [i["hostId"] for i in meetingList]
```

You could also use list comprehension here but if you aren't familiar with it, this for loop and if logic will print out any member id who isn't a host.

```
for i in member_id_list:
    if i not in meeting_hostid_list:
        print(i)

>> 3
```